# Trying to read files in a zip archive without extracting them

Tags: ruby, zip

I've been trying to read the contents of a zipped file for the sake of data comparison, similar to the person from this thread: [Reading files in a zip archive, without unzipping the archive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28100888/reading-files-in-a-zip-archive-without-unzipping-the-archive)

I tried the accepted code there exactly, but I'm still getting the error
`` /home/fikayo/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rubyzip-1.2.0/lib/zip/file.rb:73:in `size?': no implicit conversion of Zip::Entry into String (TypeError) ``

For reference, here is my code:

```
 require 'rubygems'
 require 'zip'

      def read_file
        Zip::File.open(myZip) do |zip_file|
          zip_file.each do |entry|
            if entry.directory?
              puts "#{entry.name} is a folder!"
            elsif entry.symlink?
              puts "#{entry.name} is a symlink!"
            elsif entry.file?
              puts "#{entry.name} is a regular file!"

              # Read into memory
              content = entry.get_input_stream.read

              # Output
              puts content
            else
              puts "No sell"
            end
          end
        end
      end
```

`myZip` is the variable that I stored the zip file inside. I checked to make sure and its type is listed as `Zip::Entry`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [rubyzip documentation](https://github.com/rubyzip/rubyzip#reading-a-zip-file) (and the question you linked) `mZip` should be of class `String` and contain the **path to a file** rather than `File` or `Zip::Entry`.

```
mZip = './folder/file.zip'
def read_file
  Zip::File.open(myZip) do |zip_file|
  #...
end
```